# Where can I download the native Android .ogg files?

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to support from API level 14 in my app, but the `MediaActionSound` class is only supported from API level 16. I found out that I can use this code snippet to play the required sound:

```
int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            maSound = new MediaActionSound();
            maSound.load(MediaActionSound.FOCUS_COMPLETE);
        } else {
            SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0);
            int shutterSound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.focus_complete, 0);  
        }
```

where `R.raw.focus_complete` is the reference to the audio `.ogg` file for that sound.

However I do not know where to download the standard `.ogg` files for the sounds `FOCUS_COMPLETE` and `START_VIDEO_RECORDING`.

Can anyone refer me to the URL or is there an alternative way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a quick look into MediaActionSound.java.  You have this :

```
private static final String[] SOUND_FILES = {
    "/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg",
    "/system/media/audio/ui/camera_focus.ogg",
    "/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg",
    "/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg"
};
```

So it seems you can use this [load method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) :

```
soundPool.load("/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg",1);
```